# Keyboard not displayed onClick EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I'm struggling to get my keyboard to display in my EditText. When I click the EditText for the first time, the keyboard displays and behaves normally.

When I press the back button to hide the keyboard and click the same EditText again, the keyboard fails to display. I'd really appreciate any help. The relevant code is below.

NewEntry:

```
assessor.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(context.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                        EditText email = (EditText) context.findViewById(R.id.email);

                        email.requestFocus();

                        return true;
                    }
```

Layout:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/assessor"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:hint="Assessor"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:ems="10"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

set an onClickListener for the EditText, and when it is clicked it will request focus

```
EditTextName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

editText.requestFocus();

}
```

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but at least i tried :P

Comment: I think it has to do with the.     HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS. Why do you need that part?